Python Script to grab .geojson files from my N drive in many different folders and place in one folder?
Is there a Python Script to grab .geojson files from my N drive in many different folders and place in one folder? They all have different names. And in some cases there are multiple geojsons and ideally I only want to move the most recently created one. My ultimate goal is to then take this folder full of .geojson files and run a Arc GIS pro batch data import tool. Who can help me?
I have 0 python experience. If you could explain it like I am 5 that would amazing.
This solution was provided and I am trying it out.
import os
from shutil import copyfile
n_drive_path = r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/" #The folder to seach geojson files in. Change it
out_folder = r"/home/bera/Desktop/test/" #The folder to copy them to. Change it

files_to_copy = [] #An empty list
for root, folder, files in os.walk(n_drive_path):
    for file in files: #For each file in all folders and subfolders in n_drive_path
        if file.endswith(".geojson"): #If it is a geojson
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file) #Create a full path to the file
            files_to_copy.append(fullname) #Append it to the list

#print(files_to_copy)
#['/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/points_on_lines.geojson', '/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/nearly_identical_points.geojson', '/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/Rectangle_lines.geojson', '/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/nearly_identical_points2.geojson']

for srcfile in files_to_copy: #For each file in the list
    #srcfile is for example: '/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/nearly_identical_points2.geojson'
    filename = os.path.basename(srcfile) #Extract only the filename from the full path
    dstfile = os.path.join(out_folder, filename)
    #Dstfile is now: '/home/bera/Desktop/test/nearly_identical_points2.geojson'
    copyfile(src=srcfile, dst=dstfile)


If you don't have programming knowledge, I recommend to go through some Python tutorials to understand the basics of programming languages, otherwise it will be difficult to comprehend any script.
You already got some good answers over in GIS StackExchange. However, you added "[...] ideally I only want to move the most recently created one." in your question here. So this answer will add that missing piece plus provides you with some additional links.
The following example uses pathlib.Path instead of os.
The result of Path(SOURCE_FOLDER).glob("**/*.geojson") allows you to iterate over all GeoJSON files within the given folder and it's subfolder.
You can leverage pathlib.Path.stats().st_ctime in Python 3.11.x or older to retrieve the file's creation timestamp.
Finally, to copy the file, you can use shutil.copyfile.
I tried to use as descriptive variable names as possible in the example:
import shutil                  # needed to copy file

from datetime import datetime  # needed to get current timestamp
from pathlib import Path       # needed for file related operations


SOURCE_FOLDER = "d:/data"
DESTINATION_FOLDER = "c:/temp"

# ignores files that are older than MAX_AGE_IN_DAYS days
MAX_AGE_IN_DAYS = 365


# calculate the earliest file creation timestamp
now = datetime.now().timestamp()
max_age_in_seconds = MAX_AGE_IN_DAYS * 86400
earliest_file_creation_timestamp = now - max_age_in_seconds


# iterate over all geojson files in the source folder and its subfolders
for file in Path(SOURCE_FOLDER).glob("**/*.geojson"):
    
    # get the file creation timestamp
    file_creation_timestamp = file.stat().st_ctime        # Python 3.11.x or older
    # file_creation_timestamp = file.stat().st_birthtime  # Python 3.12 or newer

    # is the file's creation timestamp newer than the calculated 
    # earliest creation timestamp
    if (file_creation_timestamp > earliest_file_creation_timestamp):   
        
        # copy file
        shutil.copyfile(file, Path(DESTINATION_FOLDER) / file.name)

If you are using Python 3.12 or newer, you'll need to use pathlib.Path.stats().st_birthtime instead of pathlib.Path.stats().st_ctime.
If you prefer to use the module os (as shown in BERA's example on GIS StackExchange) instead of pathlib, you may want to look at os.stat() and os.stat().st_ctime to retrieve the creation date of a file on Windows. Here as well, for Python 3.12 or newer, use st_birthtime instead.

You can then also leverage arcpy.conversion.JSONToFeatures to import the GeoJSON files.
Here is an example that imports the GeoJSON files into a Geodatabase (without copy the files to another folder though):
import arcpy                   # needed to import GeoJSON into GDB

from datetime import datetime  # needed to get current timestamp
from pathlib import Path       # needed for file related operations


SOURCE_FOLDER = "d:/data"
GEODATABASE = "c:/temp/features.gdb"

# ignores files that are older than MAX_AGE_IN_DAYS days
MAX_AGE_IN_DAYS = 365


# calculate the earliest file creation timestamp
now = datetime.now().timestamp()
max_age_in_seconds = MAX_AGE_IN_DAYS * 86400
earliest_file_creation_timestamp = now - max_age_in_seconds


# iterate over all geojson files in the source folder and its subfolders
for file in Path(SOURCE_FOLDER).glob("**/*.geojson"):
    
    # get the file creation timestamp
    file_creation_timestamp = file.stat().st_ctime

    # is the file's creation timestamp newer than the calculated 
    # earliest creation timestamp
    if (file_creation_timestamp > earliest_file_creation_timestamp):   
        
        # import feature
        arcpy.conversion.JSONToFeatures(
                              str(file), str(Path(GEODATABASE) / file.stem)

Notes:

The above example casts the Path object to a string using str() which is required (arcpy cannot work with Path objects).
ArcGIS Pro is - as of today - not using Python 3.12, therefore, you can use st_ctime.
Instead of using file.name, the example uses file.stem to remove the file extension.
There are some restrictions for the feature naming in geodatabases. For example if your file name has spaces, the example above will fail. You would need to remove the spaces (and other illegal characters). Spaces could be removed by using str.replace, for example: file.stem.replace(" ", "").

